# WPF Application performance - Fine on Intel, Extremely Slow on AMD

Tags: wpf, performance

We have a WPF application (.NET 4.5) that is running perfectly fine in most environments we have tried it on.  However, on some AMD processor based platforms the performance is a nightmare and the application is virtually unusable.  We have put platforms out on Azure and Amazon VM's with identical specs besides processor type Intel vs AMD.  We have a laptop internally running AMD that is horrible as well.

We do have a machine with an AMD processor that uses an ATI video card.  The performance is normal there.  The laptop we have in house uses the onboard video and the VM uses VGA from the VM itself (both have poor performance).

I have looked at PriorityBoostEnabled and RenderMode, which hasn't helped and searched the web looking for similar issues, but haven't found much out there.

There is a similar thread on serverfault that hasn't gotten much attention.  This is a standard .NET app and I don't see how it can be a coding issue.  I have never put anything in any code before to target an AMD process different than an Intel based CPU.

Here's the serverfault thread:  https://serverfault.com/questions/617779/wpf-application-issues-on-amd-cpu-vs-intel

Comment: `I don't see how it can be a coding issue.` If it's not a coding issue, then this is probably the wrong place to ask. If it is a coding issue, can you come up with a simple demonstration?

Comment: @MattBurland Maybe there is some setting somewhere that needs to be modified on AMD.  ie. Registry or who knows.  I've seen weirder things.  The post on serverfault got nowhere and it could be possible another developer has encountered something similar and could provide insight so I don't think it's the wrong place.  The application is massive and would be hard to reproduce.  I know that makes it more difficult, but worth throwing out here.

Comment: Based on this description there's really a small chance for us to debug this for you. I can tell you for sure that it isn't AMD vs Intel, because I have both platforms and never ran into any issues with WPF. We can just place bets what the problem actually is, but without any code or additional info, this is a very vague description. Try to read your post from our perspective - would you be able to give any advice?

Comment: Is this all WPF applications or just this one in particular?

Comment: @walther I do understand that point.  We created two VMs spec for spec on Azure, Amazon and locally. It only runs poorly where AMD is the processor in Azure and functions that way on the single piece of AMD hardware we have internally.  I understand it's vague and hard to debug, but the only difference we see is Intel vs AMD.

Comment: Well as I read your post over and over, I see a difference - graphics cards. Emulated and onboard => bad performance, but if you use NVIDIA, it suddenly works on AMD as well. So it seems to me it's a problem with graphics rendering as Brian suggested.

Comment: @walther Agreed, the only true difference I see is the graphics stack.

Comment: @BrianRudolph We did discuss this.  However, I still wanted to see if anyone had encountered anything similar.  An answer of AMD, is a no-no in our Minimum Sys Requirements might not go over so well.  AMD is pretty widely used.

Comment: Random idea, but have you tried renaming the executable? Perhaps the AMD drivers are detecting it as a game and are trying to optimize it and failing... Complete shot in the dark though.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: Download WPf performance suite and see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a very concrete answer, but it almost assuredly comes down to whether or not WPF is detecting that it can render in hardware or not.  If WPF drops to software rendering, there are many UI elements that will absolutely destroy performance(ie. drop shadows).

Here is more information about the [rendering pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613578.aspx).

In a VM, you may not have access to ANY hardware rendering, which would account for the performance issue.  On the AMD hardware you are looking at, the on-board graphics system may not support Direct X 7.0 or higher, which would drop to software rendering.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The laptop running AMD is x64 and DirectX 11.  I did check RenderMode as I briefly mentioned in the question.  Render Mode of 2 is being reported on the AMD x64 unit with the poor performance and I'm getting a Mode of 2 on a standard Win7 and Win7 32 and 64 bit Intel environments.

Comment: @Matt How are you checking the rendering mode?  Are you using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rendercapability.tier.aspx at runtime?

Comment: at startup I prompted the render mode exactly as described in the article in a MessageBox

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately I would still guess it's a graphics issue.  Perhaps driver incompatibility, or likewise.  There are many documented cases of WPF performance issues with AMD\ATI graphics.  Even if the system detects it can render in Layer 2, you have no guarantee that the driver isn't offloading processing to CPU, or DX itself could be offloading certain calcs and textures to system memory.