# WPF application performace poor on AMD, fine on intel?

Tags: wpf

Background

Im in the process of developing a telemetry app that shows some data from a model aeroplane. The app features a artificial horizon to show the aircraft's attitude. This is done by mooving around png images and is the probable the most processor intensive part of the system.

I have had no issues with my app until I bought a new laptop to use for primarily coding. I had tested the app on a number of machines but these all featured intel CPU's. On these the application ran fine.

When i tried to run this app on my new laptop (Ryzen 4500U and RADEON Graphics) the performace of the system is very poor and totaly un useable. Telemetry data is sent every 0.1 seconds and it lags far behing this which i believe to be unacceptable, considering it ran fine on a much lower speced laptop.

[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1MYw.png)

What ive tried

The obvious first move was to update the drivers for my laptop, which i did, no changes.

So Ive been trying to find a solution for the past few hours with no luck. There is a similar question [WPF Application performance - Fine on Intel, Extremely Slow on AMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314315/wpf-application-performance-fine-on-intel-extremely-slow-on-amd). This has similar problems and suspects acelleration. Ive tried turning this off in visual studio but it made no difference. I also had a brief go at trying to edit the regisrty to disable hardware acceleration, but this didnt work.

Here is a link to the entire project code, if you wish to check it out. Bear in mind its a WIP and im mediocre at WPF. [code](https://github.com/georgegohl888/groundstation)

Any Ideas?

Comment: What OS are you on? Also what process is slow? User interface or something else? Are all the process intensive on separate threads and not on the GUI thread?

Comment: All machines were on the latest windows 10. rendering the attitude indicator (blue and brown) is the slow bit.

Comment: I highly recommend that you use GitHub to share your code. Putting a zip file on a file sharing site is too high friction and risky for folks who might want to help you.

Comment: hi, thanks for the sugestion. uploaded to git and question updated.